# Ctrl+C в subproccess python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть внешняя программа, которая запускается через `subprocess`. Проблема заключается в корректном завершении внешней программы. Просто убить процесс не вариант, т.к по нажатию CTRL+C выполняется важное действие перед завершением.

Как передать программе сигнал завершения посредством subproccess?

Comment: Не понимаю. Вы хотите передать программе сигнал завершения, но убить процесс нельзя? Т.е. внешняя программа должна завершиться сама?

Comment: Ну например есть тип исключения KeyboardInterrupt. Вот мне нужно что-бы блок except сработал во внешней программе, только она не написана на python. Вообщем да, она должна выполнить определенное действие и завершиться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Unix, если вы нажмёте [<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> в shell, то `SIGINT` сигнал посылается всем процессам в текущей группе процессов](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149756/1321). То есть, обычно, *ничего* не надо делать, чтобы дочерний процесс отреагировал на <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. Проверьте игнорируется ли SIGINT в вашем процессе (`SIG_IGN` наследуется) или принадлежит ли дочерний процесс текущей (foreground) группе процессов (текущая задача/job/pipeline в bash, если аналоги [`os.setsid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html), [`os.setpgrp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgrp.html) не вызываются).

Вы можете послать `SIGINT` явно одному процессу, созданному с помощью `subprocess.Popen()`: `process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)`. Вот [пример кода, который посылает `SIGINT` через 5 секунд после запуска `ping` процесса](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27995163/4279). Можно [послать сигнал всей группе процессов, используя `os.killpg()`, чтобы эмулировать <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> в Питоне](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279).

На Windows, можно [`signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` или `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) послать консольным приложениям (процессам в той же консоли).

Answer (score 1):

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import subprocess, time, signal, ctypes

proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd\n', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
proc.stdin.write('ping 127.0.0.1 -t\n'.encode())
proc.stdin.close()

time.sleep(3)

ctypes.windll.kernel32.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0, proc.pid)
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)

for a in proc.stdout:
    try: print(a.decode('cp866', 'ignore'))
    except:pass
```

out:

```
C:\Python344\python.exe E:/python/2016/6/12312.py
^C(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2013. Все права защищены.



E:\python\2016\6>ping 127.0.0.1 -t



Обмен пакетами с 127.0.0.1 по с 32 байтами данных:

Ответ от 127.0.0.1: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=128

Ответ от 127.0.0.1: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=128

Ответ от 127.0.0.1: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=128



Статистика Ping для 127.0.0.1:

    Пакетов: отправлено = 3, получено = 3, потеряно = 0

    (0% потерь)

Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:

    Минимальное = 0мсек, Максимальное = 0 мсек, Среднее = 0 мсек

Control-C



E:\python\2016\6>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: А как будет выглядеть подобный код для Linux?

Answer (score -1):

в питон поставьте блок

```
try:
  #ваш код 
finally:
  #что должно произойти
```

питон перед удалением самого себя выполнит условие )